# Change SVG ClipPath on Hover

Tags: css, svg

I have a SVG navigation wheel which I've put up on jsfiddle [SVG navigation wheel](https://jsfiddle.net/ajjp5o7/oqu5wj79/)

here is the actual SVG code:

```
<svg  id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 555.13 552.81" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<title>wheelv2</title>
  <g id="INCUBATION_SERVICES" data-name="INCUBATION SERVICES">
   <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M277.31,277.56V20.41A257.15,257.15,0,0,0,54.63,149Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <g id="_Group_" data-name=" Group ">
      <path class="cls-2" d="M193.69,85.79a30.67,30.67,0,0,1,22.7,35.14,5.2,5.2,0,0,0-6.64,3.17h0l-.07.22a6.66,6.66,0,0,1-1-8.63,8.94,8.94,0,0,0-6.9-14.93,12,12,0,0,0-6.43-9.91,3.34,3.34,0,0,1-.64-.33A3.43,3.43,0,0,1,193.69,85.79Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
      <path class="cls-2" d="M211.19,124a3.42,3.42,0,0,1,4.73-1h0a30.68,30.68,0,0,1-35.14,22.69,5.2,5.2,0,0,0-3.17-6.64h0l-.22-.07a6.66,6.66,0,0,1,8.64-1A8.94,8.94,0,0,0,201,131.1a12,12,0,0,0,9.91-6.43A3.42,3.42,0,0,1,211.19,124Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
      <circle class="cls-2" cx="202.67" cy="107.97" r="6.76"/>
      <circle class="cls-2" cx="192.47" cy="130.53" r="6.76"/>
      <path class="cls-2" d="M194.77,92,195,92a6.66,6.66,0,0,1-8.64,1,8.94,8.94,0,0,0-14.93,6.9,12,12,0,0,0-9.91,6.43,3.61,3.61,0,0,1-.33.64,3.43,3.43,0,0,1-4.74,1,30.67,30.67,0,0,1,35.19-22.68A5.2,5.2,0,0,0,194.77,92Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
      <circle class="cls-2" cx="180.11" cy="97.77" r="6.76"/>
      <path class="cls-2" d="M177.69,140.53a3.43,3.43,0,0,1,1,4.74A30.67,30.67,0,0,1,156,110.14a5.2,5.2,0,0,0,6.64-3.17h0l.07-.22a6.66,6.66,0,0,1,1,8.63,8.94,8.94,0,0,0,6.9,14.93,12,12,0,0,0,6.43,9.91A3.34,3.34,0,0,1,177.69,140.53Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
      <circle class="cls-2" cx="169.91" cy="120.33" r="6.76"/>
    </g>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(65.52 123.08) rotate(-53.44)">I</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="matrix(0.63, -0.78, 0.78, 0.63, 69, 118.24)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(78.02 107.02) rotate(-48.18)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(86.97 96.99) rotate(-45.22)">U</text>
    <text class="cls-4" transform="matrix(0.74, -0.67, 0.67, 0.74, 96.67, 87.21)">B</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(106.35 78.36) rotate(-39.29)">A</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(116.23 70.25) rotate(-36.8)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-5" transform="matrix(0.82, -0.57, 0.57, 0.82, 125.79, 63.16)">I</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(130.6 59.68) rotate(-32.48)">O</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(143.68 51.36) rotate(-29.21)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-6" transform="translate(161.13 41.86) rotate(-24.78)">S</text>
    <text class="cls-7" transform="translate(171.67 36.89) rotate(-22.44)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="matrix(0.94, -0.34, 0.34, 0.94, 182.9, 32.21)">R</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(194.93 27.87) rotate(-16.84)">V</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(208.13 23.94) rotate(-14.66)">I</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(213.9 22.35) rotate(-12.51)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-8" transform="translate(227.02 19.45) rotate(-9.74)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-3" transform="matrix(0.99, -0.12, 0.12, 0.99, 239.04, 17.39)">S</text>
      </a>
  </g>
  <g id="CHURCH_OUTREACH" data-name="CHURCH OUTREACH">
   <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <path class="cls-9" d="M277.31,277.56,54.63,149a257.15,257.15,0,0,0,0,257.15Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path id="church-building" class="cls-2" d="M109.52,277.6a1.7,1.7,0,0,0-.22-.51L89,257.26v-9.34h3.28a1.76,1.76,0,1,0,0-3.52H89V241a1.81,1.81,0,0,0-3.61,0v3.44H81.81a1.76,1.76,0,1,0,0,3.52h3.55v9.31L65,277.14a1.92,1.92,0,0,0-.22.51v28.8a.75.75,0,0,0,.75.72H80.74a.76.76,0,0,0,.75-.72V294.19a5.65,5.65,0,0,1,11.29-.48q0,.24,0,.48V306.4a.76.76,0,0,0,.75.72H108.8a.75.75,0,0,0,.75-.72Zm-22.36,2.74A5.84,5.84,0,1,1,93,274.49s0,0,0,0a5.84,5.84,0,0,1-5.84,5.83Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <text class="cls-10" transform="translate(37.35 379.72) rotate(-111.7)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-11" transform="matrix(-0.32, -0.95, 0.95, -0.32, 32.34, 367.25)">H</text>
    <text class="cls-12" transform="translate(27.88 354.19) rotate(-105.78)">U</text>
    <text class="cls-12" transform="translate(24.13 340.95) rotate(-102.81)">R</text>
    <text class="cls-12" transform="matrix(-0.17, -0.99, 0.99, -0.17, 21.2, 328.13)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-13" transform="matrix(-0.12, -0.99, 0.99, -0.12, 18.88, 314.9)">H</text>
    <text class="cls-12" transform="matrix(-0.04, -1, 1, -0.04, 16.72, 295.76)">O</text>
    <text class="cls-14" transform="translate(16.02 280.29) rotate(-88.85)">U</text>
    <text class="cls-12" transform="translate(16.22 266.46) rotate(-86.61)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-12" transform="matrix(0.11, -0.99, 0.99, 0.11, 16.89, 254.72)">R</text>
    <text class="cls-15" transform="translate(18.3 241.6) rotate(-81.38)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-14" transform="matrix(0.2, -0.98, 0.98, 0.2, 20.13, 229.59)">A</text>
    <text class="cls-16" transform="translate(22.89 216.31) rotate(-75.55)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-12" transform="translate(26.27 203.33) rotate(-72.3)">H</text>
      </a>
  </g>

    <path class="cls-17" d="M277.31,277.56,54.63,406.14A257.15,257.15,0,0,0,277.31,534.7Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M175.63,431.24l.09-.35h0l2.56-2.65,4.84-4.84h0l.14-.13.6-.58-.66-.67c-1-1.06-2.79-2.83-3.25-3.18a19.88,19.88,0,0,0-26.17,29.84c.67.56,2.44,2.19,2.46,2.21l.07.07a2.82,2.82,0,0,1,.37-.8,26.25,26.25,0,0,1,3.11-3.22l.07-.07h.08l.13-.07.18-.09.14-.06.19-.07.15,0,.2-.06H162l13.08-13.33Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M210.94,451.14l-20.83-20.83-5.48,5.58-1,3.54a8.21,8.21,0,0,1-4.66,5.38,7.26,7.26,0,0,1-.86.3l-.61.14a11.54,11.54,0,0,1-1.84.1c-1.12,0-2.35-.06-2.83-.09h-1l3.19-12-13,13h.1a4.43,4.43,0,0,1,3.16,1.3l.68.68.26.29,0,.07h0l.16.21.06.09h0l.14.23.06.1.12.23h0v.07c0,.12.1.24.14.35h0q0,.16.09.32v.09h0v2l.3-.06h.78a4.44,4.44,0,0,1,3.16,1.3l.68.68.21.23.06.07.14.17.06.09.12.18,0,.08.16.28h0l.08.17h0l.1.27a4,4,0,0,1,.29,1.38h0v1.27l.29-.06h.81a4.43,4.43,0,0,1,3.16,1.3l.68.68.27.29.06.07h0l.16.21.07.1h0l.13.21.07.12.11.23h0v.08a1.1,1.1,0,0,0,.12.31h0a1.61,1.61,0,0,0,.1.36v1.12h0V464a.8.8,0,0,1-.06.37v.2l.27,0h.72a4.43,4.43,0,0,1,3.15,1.3l.68.68.27.3,0,.07v.06l.14.19.06.09,0,.08.1.16.06.11v.09l.08.15,0,.12V468l.06.17v.5h0V469h0v1.73l0,.18-.07.19-.07.17-.09.19-.08.17-.08.15.85.85a3.18,3.18,0,0,0,4.47,0l.68-.68a3.18,3.18,0,0,0,0-4.48l-15-15,.92-.92,15.7,15.7a3.18,3.18,0,0,0,4.48,0l.68-.68a3.17,3.17,0,0,0,0-4.47l-15.7-15.7.92-.92,16.26,16.26a3.18,3.18,0,0,0,4.47,0l.68-.68a3.17,3.17,0,0,0,0-4.48l-15.9-16.14.9-.9.53.49,16.31,16.31a3.18,3.18,0,0,0,4.47,0l.68-.68a3.17,3.17,0,0,0,0-4.47Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M167.38,462.14a3.14,3.14,0,0,1-2.24-.92l-.68-.68a3.17,3.17,0,0,1,0-4.47l1.52-1.52.26-.23a3.21,3.21,0,0,1,4.24.23l.68.68a3.12,3.12,0,0,1,.86,1.65V457a3.19,3.19,0,0,1-.66,2.42l-.23.26-1.5,1.43A3.14,3.14,0,0,1,167.38,462.14Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M173.48,468.14a3.14,3.14,0,0,1-2.24-.92l-.68-.68a3.18,3.18,0,0,1,0-4.48l1.52-1.52.24-.21a3.17,3.17,0,0,1,2-.71,3.21,3.21,0,0,1,.92.14l.36.13a3.14,3.14,0,0,1,1,.65l.68.68a3.19,3.19,0,0,1,.21,4.24l-.22.24-1.52,1.52A3.14,3.14,0,0,1,173.48,468.14Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M179.49,474.33a3.14,3.14,0,0,1-2.24-.92l-.68-.68a3.17,3.17,0,0,1,0-4.48l1.52-1.52a3.09,3.09,0,0,1,.32-.27,3.18,3.18,0,0,1,1.93-.65,3.13,3.13,0,0,1,2.23.92l.68.68a3.2,3.2,0,0,1,0,4.48l-1.52,1.52A3.14,3.14,0,0,1,179.49,474.33Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M161.28,456a3.14,3.14,0,0,1-2.24-.92l-.68-.68a3.17,3.17,0,0,1,0-4.48l1.52-1.52a3.18,3.18,0,0,1,4.48,0l.68.68a3.17,3.17,0,0,1,.25,4.19h0a3.22,3.22,0,0,1-.24.27l-1.54,1.56A3.14,3.14,0,0,1,161.28,456Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M212.78,451.33l-3.83-4-.64-.66h0l-18.2-18.2-6.7,6.7-1,3.88a6.78,6.78,0,0,1-5.11,4.87,10.49,10.49,0,0,1-1.61.08c-.73,0-1.52,0-2.12,0l3.21-12.1.12-.46,8.08-8.08h0l.59-.59h0l.67-.68c1-1.06,2.79-2.83,3.25-3.18a19.88,19.88,0,0,1,26.14,29.86C215,449.22,213.28,450.86,212.78,451.33Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <text class="cls-18" transform="matrix(-0.99, -0.14, 0.14, -0.99, 248.81, 536.08)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-18" transform="translate(235.89 534.37) rotate(-169.14)">O</text>
    <text class="cls-19" transform="matrix(-0.97, -0.24, 0.24, -0.97, 220.67, 531.45)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-18" transform="matrix(-0.96, -0.29, 0.29, -0.96, 206.69, 527.9)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-20" transform="translate(195.33 524.37) rotate(-160.84)">I</text>
    <text class="cls-21" transform="translate(189.66 522.52) rotate(-158.84)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-22" transform="translate(176.26 517.3) rotate(-155.75)">U</text>
    <text class="cls-18" transform="matrix(-0.89, -0.46, 0.46, -0.89, 163.73, 511.64)">U</text>
    <text class="cls-23" transform="translate(151.54 505.37) rotate(-149.33)">M</text>
    <text class="cls-24" transform="matrix(-0.82, -0.58, 0.58, -0.82, 133.35, 494.35)">O</text>
    <text class="cls-18" transform="translate(120.69 485.35) rotate(-141.75)">F</text>
    <text class="cls-25" transform="matrix(-0.74, -0.67, 0.67, -0.74, 107.13, 474.48)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-26" transform="matrix(-0.7, -0.71, 0.71, -0.7, 97.18, 465.49)">A</text>
    <text class="cls-18" transform="translate(87.04 455.26) rotate(-131.77)">R</text>
    <text class="cls-18" transform="translate(78.26 445.43) rotate(-129)">E</text>
      </a>
  </g>
  <g id="CARE_CLINICS" data-name="CARE CLINICS">
   <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <path class="cls-27" d="M277.31,277.56V534.7A257.15,257.15,0,0,0,500,406.14Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M347.51,457.35q2.36-7.94,4.71-15.88c.9-3,1.75-6,2.81-9a11.24,11.24,0,0,1,8.9-7.85,11.11,11.11,0,0,1,2.06-.13c5.42,0,10.84.08,16.25,0a11.06,11.06,0,0,1,11,7.56c2.58,7.92,5,15.89,7.35,23.86.88,3-.92,5.08-3.91,4.88a3.3,3.3,0,0,1-3.1-2.69q-2.07-6.68-4.13-13.37c-.87-2.83-1.7-5.66-2.55-8.5h-3.27l2.85,9.46,7.65,25.41c.09.29.14.59.21.88H355.5l-1.34-.37,10.67-35.38h-3.2c-.14.43-.26.8-.37,1.17-2.09,6.88-4.17,13.76-6.3,20.63a4.2,4.2,0,0,1-1.22,2c-2.09,1.71-4.75.88-6.23-1.84Zm26.67,12.3c7.34,0,13-5.41,13-12.29s-5.84-12.39-13.48-12.3c-6.93.08-12.62,6-12.48,12.46a12.62,12.62,0,0,0,13,12.13Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M374.52,405.14a10.6,10.6,0,0,1,6,2.61,8,8,0,0,1,1.64,9.5A9.2,9.2,0,0,1,373,421.8a9,9,0,0,1-7.49-6.92,8.26,8.26,0,0,1,4.73-8.66c.93-.44,1.93-.72,2.91-1.07Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M369.8,461.09c-1.07.61-2,1.13-3,1.68a1.33,1.33,0,0,1-1.86-.25l-.06-.08a1.06,1.06,0,0,1,.34-1.69c1.3-.89,2.6-1.78,4-2.56a1.7,1.7,0,0,1,2.46.7,19.79,19.79,0,0,1,1,1.87l1.82-3.39c-2.58-.3-3-2.32-3.92-4a1.09,1.09,0,0,1,.6-1.71c.43-.14,1.07.27,1.61.44a.31.31,0,0,1,.08.1c.79,2.32,2.88,2.83,5,3.4s2.66,1.66,1.7,3.63c-.64,1.3-1.36,2.56-2,3.84a3.75,3.75,0,0,1-3.78,2.1,3.71,3.71,0,0,1-3.41-2.44C370.22,462.25,370.06,461.76,369.8,461.09Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M381.48,451.68a3.12,3.12,0,0,1-3.16,3,3,3,0,0,1-3-3s0-.05,0-.08a2.88,2.88,0,0,1,2.92-2.84h.08a3,3,0,0,1,3.16,2.83S381.48,451.65,381.48,451.68Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(494.33 422.71) rotate(126.44)">W</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(482.54 438.61) rotate(130.19)">O</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(472.59 450.43) rotate(133.6)">M</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(461.62 461.89) rotate(136.64)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(452.81 470.27) rotate(139.54)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="matrix(-0.78, 0.62, -0.62, -0.78, 441.7, 479.64)">’</text>
    <text class="cls-29" transform="translate(437.74 482.84) rotate(143.59)">S</text>
    <text class="cls-30" transform="matrix(-0.84, 0.54, -0.54, -0.84, 423.93, 492.88)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-31" transform="translate(412.64 500.12) rotate(150.61)">A</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(400.11 507.21) rotate(153.52)">R</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(388.32 513.09) rotate(156.31)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="matrix(-0.94, 0.34, -0.34, -0.94, 372.11, 520.03)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(359.41 524.55) rotate(163.07)">L</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(348.56 527.81) rotate(164.98)">I</text>
    <text class="cls-32" transform="translate(342.82 529.45) rotate(167.35)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(328.63 532.58) rotate(169.5)">I</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="matrix(-0.99, 0.15, -0.15, -0.99, 322.76, 533.75)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-28" transform="translate(309.44 535.69) rotate(174.39)">S</text>
      </a>
  </g>
  <g id="CONTACT_CENTER" data-name="CONTACT CENTER">
   <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <path class="cls-33" d="M277.31,277.56,500,406.14A257.15,257.15,0,0,0,500,149Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <path class="cls-2" d="M485.34,289.36V271.95a8.46,8.46,0,0,0-5-7.7,6.64,6.64,0,0,0,2.86-5.47,6.75,6.75,0,1,0-10.45,5.72,8.68,8.68,0,0,0-4.32,5.16,9.67,9.67,0,0,0-5.53-8.18,7.54,7.54,0,1,0-8.49.15,9.28,9.28,0,0,0-5.25,8.36v19.38h-9.43v4.29h55.62v-4.29Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="matrix(0.29, 0.96, -0.96, 0.29, 525.72, 193.22)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(529.56 205.69) rotate(76.19)">O</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(533.26 220.72) rotate(79.48)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(535.87 234.89) rotate(82.35)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-35" transform="translate(537.29 244.9) rotate(84.86)">A</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(538.53 258.43) rotate(87.69)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="matrix(-0.02, 1, -1, -0.02, 539.11, 271.81)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(538.79 289.12) rotate(94.32)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(537.78 302.55) rotate(97.11)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="matrix(-0.17, 0.98, -0.98, -0.17, 536.31, 314.6)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(533.78 328.8) rotate(102.91)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="matrix(-0.27, 0.96, -0.96, -0.27, 531.17, 340.28)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-34" transform="translate(527.93 352.01) rotate(108.35)">R</text>
      </a>
  </g>
  <g id="MARKETING_OUTREACH" data-name="MARKETING OUTREACH">
   <a xlink:href="http://www.google.com">
    <path class="cls-36" d="M277.31,277.56,500,149A257.15,257.15,0,0,0,277.31,20.41Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    <g id="FvauEa.tif">
      <path class="cls-2" d="M346.81,136.93h3.66c0-.91.14-1.77.14-2.63V110.95c0-4.47,1.08-5.54,5.54-5.55H366l.56,5H356v26.55h11.4c1.08,0,2.19-.23,2.75,1.18.14.36,1,.57,1.57.58,2.17.07,4.34.05,6.51,0,.5,0,1.29-.1,1.44-.4.91-1.92,2.59-1.35,4.06-1.37H394c0-3.22.09-6.26,0-9.3-.07-1.63.22-2.67,2-3a17.79,17.79,0,0,0,3.3-1.42v13.66l3.27.15c1.14,4.35-.62,6.68-5,6.68-15,0-29.94-.06-44.91.06-2.93,0-4.84-.92-5.84-3.66Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
      <path class="cls-2" d="M371.48,120c4.14-2.32,2.56-4.65,1-7.44-2.87-5.2-1.44-11.47,3.1-15.66,5.54-5.12,15.36-5.92,21.63-1.77,4.4,2.92,7.19,7,6.89,12.27-.36,6.47-4.25,10.67-10.2,12.86a19,19,0,0,1-14-.42,6.4,6.4,0,0,0-2.85-.08c-1.64.16-3.27.46-4.91.7Zm22.92-14a4,4,0,0,0-5.52-3.67,3.42,3.42,0,0,1-2.29.08,3.82,3.82,0,0,0-4.82,1.06,3.46,3.46,0,0,0,.08,4.88c1.73,1.94,3.72,3.64,5.6,5.44,1.82-1.62,3.65-3.23,5.45-4.88a4.17,4.17,0,0,0,.93-1.25,12.74,12.74,0,0,0,.57-1.67Z" transform="translate(0.1 -1.38)"/>
    </g>
    <text class="cls-37" transform="translate(305.07 15.94) rotate(7.48)">M</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="translate(320.74 18.08) rotate(11.07)">A</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="matrix(0.97, 0.24, -0.24, 0.97, 334.86, 20.85)">R</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="matrix(0.96, 0.29, -0.29, 0.96, 347.64, 24.04)">K</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="matrix(0.94, 0.34, -0.34, 0.94, 360.35, 27.94)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="matrix(0.92, 0.38, -0.38, 0.92, 371.81, 32.06)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="translate(382.78 36.65) rotate(24.45)">I</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="translate(388.26 39.04) rotate(26.71)">N</text>
    <text class="cls-39" transform="translate(401.1 45.49) rotate(29.89)">G</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="translate(418.1 55.44) rotate(34.3)">O</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="translate(430.9 64.19) rotate(37.49)">U</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="translate(441.85 72.6) rotate(40.28)">T</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="translate(450.85 80.19) rotate(43)">R</text>
    <text class="cls-40" transform="matrix(0.7, 0.72, -0.72, 0.7, 460.48, 89.17)">E</text>
    <text class="cls-41" transform="matrix(0.66, 0.75, -0.75, 0.66, 468.99, 97.85)">A</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="matrix(0.62, 0.78, -0.78, 0.62, 477.99, 108.04)">C</text>
    <text class="cls-38" transform="matrix(0.58, 0.81, -0.81, 0.58, 486.36, 118.54)">H</text>
      </a>
  </g>
  </svg>
```

What i want is to be able to hover over each section of the nav wheel and have the colors inverted, in other words the icons would be filled with the background color and the backgrounds would be filled with #fff.

I watched a video that showed how to fill clipPaths with an image, but I haven't been able to figure out how to fill the clipPaths with an image only on hover.
I've seen tutorials on changing colors, but none on changing images. Is there a way to do this?

Maybe is there a way to target different paths within a group and have them respond to the hover in different ways? ie, the path for the background changes to #fff, and the path for the icon changes to its corresponding color?

Or is clipPaths the way to go?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I remember I had once the same Issue and solved it with simple javascript, try to change both styles when hovered over the element. If nobody helps you til tomorrow I will solve it. But have to go home now!

Comment: @Roman Okay, I tried every hack I could imagine and I couldn't get it to work. I'm gonna need your help if you're still willing.

Comment: The solution from Rahil works great, implement it in your svg style tag as the last css rules and change the colors to the colors you need.

Comment: I tested his approach btw. and it worked fine

Comment: Here is a working version with the first section using the approach of @Rahil Lakhani: http://www.bootply.com/VJiqBplWLS

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be able to figure it out from this, I just didn't understand how it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried for the first section and this how your code might look like.

```
#_Group_ *:hover ~ .cls-1,
.cls-1:hover { //section that you hover
  fill: #333333;
}
.cls-1:hover ~ #_Group_ path,
.cls-1:hover ~ #_Group_ circle { //inner section to over ride
  fill: #cccccc;
}


----------
```

Comment: thanks for the help! But I'm not quite sure how to implement your solution. What did your code actually look like?